# ActionBar bottom align tab icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i want to bottom align the tab icons but I have no clue how to achieve it :( I have already tried `setCustomView` without success. Although my custom layout has width and height set to `match_parent` it doesn't fill the whole tab and therefore i cannot bottom align my content.

Here are two images to illustrate what

i want to achieve

[image: This is what i want]

and what i actually get

[image: This is what i get]

Here is the custom tab view layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#f00">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have added the red background for debugging. And it really is only shown around the icon, and not the entire tab.

The 9-patch image of the tab background is:

[image]

So the fill area should be the whole image...

Comment: did you check shadow of image

Comment: shadow is your image have some area thats transparent doesnt show but he get some space ...like your image i think bottom have shadow check

Comment: ah ok, no there is no shadow/padding on the image png itself.

Comment: post your custom view layout

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you are using some 9patch image (probably generated using the ABS theme generator). The 9 patch image will determine where the region will be drawn and by default added some padding to it.

To know more about the 9 patch and how to deal with the "drawable region", please take a look of this [website](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)

**Edit**
Just in case you are too lazy to read the article in the link, a 9patch image will not only make a scalable background image, it will also able to determine the "Fill Area" of the content of its children. If the **Fill Area** is designed to be smaller than the whole image itself, padding will be added to fill the rest and hence producing what you see on the tab now.

Comment: do you mean the background drawable of the tab? Because the icon image definitely is not a 9-patch image. Just an ordinary PNG.

Comment: No, im not referring to the icon. A 9patch image is basically just a PNG with some 1 pixel border around the edge of the image. The tab which you are using has a green bottom border which is very likely to be a 9patch image. Try dive into the @drawable and find the image which is used to draw the tab, it should be named something like this : "tab_selected_xxxxxx.9.png"

Comment: of course the background drawable is a 9patch one. But it does only define the green/blue bottom line and the rest of it content area. So that shouldn't cause the problem.

Comment: Have u read the link above? Trust me, you don't know everything about 9 patch. http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/ and try to read what is "Fill Area"

Comment: I have uploaded the tab background 9-patch image to my question. It does set the whole image as "fill area".